# The newest file after unpacking file [python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

When I'm unpack file, it is not the newest. Is there any chance to upack file and change its name so it is the newest file in the directory?

```
print newest() #prints myFile.rar


if newest().endswith('.rar') or newest().endswith('.zip') :
    patoolib.extract_archive(newest(), outdir=".")
    #myFile.rar extracted to `.'. And it shows up in my directory myFile.pdf

time.sleep(20)
print  newest() #prints myFile.rar
```

My function:

```
def newest():
    path = '/home/es/ajo/files'
    os.chdir(path)
    files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)
    newest = files[-1]
return str(newest)
```

Comment: I did not see the archive but the files in the archive are extracted with their modification time at the moment they were compressed. Since `.rar` file has been copied afterwards, the archive file is the newest. Can you link to your `.rar` file so we can check?

Comment: I checked it and inside rar file is from 7 Semptember. Here is a reason :( Can I unrar this file as another name so this unpaced will be newest file? Or is any chance to do it?

Comment: please provide a link to your rar file and tell me the date of your `rar` file or provide screenshots. Other idea: if the rar file bothers you you can extract the files somewhere else so it doesn't get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy. After I unpack the file I just use function os.utime so unpacked file is the newest one in a directory :)
            ts = time.time()
            os.utime("/home/es/ajo/files/all")), (ts, ts))
It changes modified date.